Why is my else{} running 2x instead of running once when given an invalid input?
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

// Create a game of Rock Paper Scissors where you will be going up against the computer
// Super simple: Rock -> Scissors / Scissors -> Paper / Paper -> Rock

using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    char gameSelect;
    char weaponSelect;

    cout << "------------- Rock, Paper, Scissors V1.0 -------------\n";

    do{
        cout << "Would you like to play (Y/N): ";
        cin >> gameSelect;

        if(gameSelect == 'Y'){
        }
        else if(gameSelect == 'N'){
            cout << "Thank You For Playing!\n";
        }
        else{
            cout << "Invalid Input, Try Again (Y/N)\n";
        }

    }while(gameSelect != 'N');

    cout << "------------------ Established 2024 ------------------\n";

    return 0;
}

Down below is the output of the code
------------- Rock, Paper, Scissors V1.0 -------------
Would you like to play (Y/N): 1234
Invalid Input, Try Again (Y/N)
Would you like to play (Y/N): Invalid Input, Try Again (Y/N)
Would you like to play (Y/N): Invalid Input, Try Again (Y/N)
Would you like to play (Y/N): Invalid Input, Try Again (Y/N)
Would you like to play (Y/N): N
Thank You For Playing!
------------------ Established 2024 ------------------

The entirety of my code is written above. Not too sure what may be the reason for this error is as I THINK my logic is sound with my loops.
I have tried implementing
cin.clear();
fflush(stdin);

but that worked to no avail

input 1234 is read in as the chars 1, 2, 3, and 4.  That's 4 inputs

[Pro Tip] When dealing with user input the easiest way to handle crazy input is to read in the entire input into a std::string and then parse it in whatever manner you want to make sure it is valid input.  No matter if the input is good or bad you have an empty input buffer and you can proceed as the input dictates.

Debugging tip: change cout << "Invalid Input, Try Again (Y/N)\n"; to cout << gameSelect << " is invalid Input, Try Again (Y/N)\n"; so that you can see what you are working with.

You should never use fflush(stdin). See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

cin.clear(); cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
